# Fetching recordset from array

Tags: sql, arrays, postgresql, data-analysis, correlated-subquery

I'm having a column in postgresql (Table-Information) containing json format data inside an array. The column also contains NULL data
Like:

Location

NULL

[{"city":"Mumbai","state":"Maharashtra","country":"India"}]

[{"city":"Pune","state":"Maharashtra","country":"India"}]

NULL

[{"city":"Bhopal","state":"Madhya Pradesh","country":"India"}]

I want to convert it into a table with keys as column name and values as rows.

Output

city        state   country

Mumbai Maharashtra India

Pune Maharashtra India

Bhopal Madhya Pradesh India

How to get the desired output

I used unnest but it's not working, while have to hard code data for json_to_recordset.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`unnest` applies to sql arrays. For json arrays you have to use [json processing functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html#FUNCTIONS-JSON-PROCESSING-TABLE)

If all your json records have the same set of keys, then you can use `json_populate_record` after having created dynamically the right composite type :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE create_composite_type() LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
DECLARE
  column_list text ;
BEGIN
  SELECT string_agg(DISTINCT quote_ident(key) || ' text', ',')
    INTO column_list
    FROM mytable
   CROSS JOIN LATERAL json_object_keys(location->0) AS key
   LIMIT 1 ;
  
  DROP TYPE IF EXISTS composite_type ;
  EXECUTE 'CREATE TYPE composite_type AS (' || column_list || ')' ;
END ;
$$ ;

CALL create_composite_type() ;

SELECT (json_populate_record( null :: composite_type, location->0)).*
  FROM mytable;
```

Result

| city | country | state |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mumbai | India | Maharashtra |
| Pune | India | Maharashtra |
| Bhopal | India | Madhya Pradesh |

see [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/theIYOYl)